# Multiple motion events glitch and mix up

Tags: java, android, oop, touch, motion

I have 3 seperate motion events in my code, 2 are for dynamically placed objects on the screen and 1 is for my Horizontal / Vertical scroller.

The objects are placed in the scroller and whenever I try to scroll with the scroller, it glitches, (returning to x,y 0,0 position first?) and then moving.

When I remove the motionevent for one of my objects (a dynamically created grid full of seperate objects), the glitching is gone.

Which makes me believe the motionevents are getting mixed up. Because the griditems have motionevents attached which maybe makes the scroller motion event believe x,y = 0,0 before 'seeing' its own motionevent data?

Changing the motionevents to click events did not help..

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem!

The scroller motion event was added in the code later then the 2 other motion events, all I had to do was move the scroller motion event above the other motion events.. Yes, that's all..